# Is there a way to change scrollbar width?

Tags: node-editor, interface, customization

I work on a 15' laptop and the scrollbar width takes a lot of space when working on multiple windows. Being able to hide the scrollbar or changing the width to a minimal value would help me a lot.

I've gone through every setting in User Preferences to search for a solution but couldn't find a way.
Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

One way to scale scrollbars is... to scale everything: since 2.79, you can scale the UI through a global factor (default to 1). This is useful on hidpi displays, but it could help you too:

by default, the UI as 1.0 scaling factor:

[image]

but you can scale it down enough to get all the UI (and also scrollbars) slimmer:

[image]

of course now everything is too small, but in Blender you can also scale each area/panel (<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>MMB drag</kbd>): of course par of the UI (menu and icons) cannot be resized in this way, but you can at least find a compromise...

[image]

Comment: This worked. Thank you! Only problem is I can't resize the bottom toolbar to the original size, as you said. Hopefully they'll add the option soon. :)